# Prevent duplicates in mysql group by with join statement

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I've got a problem that can't be new, but I can't figure out how to get the answer I want. It is probably something simple that I'm missing

Using mysql 5.5, I have 2 tables, 'referrals' and 'status'. I want to count referrals that have been cancelled, grouped by appt_date:

```
SELECT SUM(1) AS count, appt_date FROM referrals
GROUP BY appt_date
JOIN status ON referrals.id=status.referral_id
WHERE status.status_name="cancelled"
```

This works fine until I have a referral that gets cancelled twice. In other words, a referral with a given id that has 2 rows in the status table with matching referral_id will get counted twice.

How to count each referral record only once when doing the join operation here?

EDIT:
My real question should have been this:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) AS count, appt_date FROM referrals
GROUP BY appt_date
JOIN status ON referrals.id=status.referral_id
WHERE status.status_name="cancelled"
```

since each referral can have its own quantity.

Comment: Based on the answer offered by IrishDubGuy, I see I should have not tried to simplify my question. Question edited above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing count to count(DISTINCT id)

Comment: Or rather change `SUM(1)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT id)`.

Comment: This works of course, thanks for the answer. I tried to simplify my question and I guess I shouldn't have now that I see the answer here. See my edited question for the real query.

Answer (score 1):

So count was only a label, I should have seen that :)

The temptation is to do SUM(DISTINCT quantity) but obviously will just remove dupe "quantities", which isn't what you want. It looks like you will need to join on a derived select table. Have a look at this...

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-with-distinct-aggregates-and-derived-tables

Comment: Yes, count was a label (bad choice in retrospect) but you were spot on for my original question. The link you provided was perfect, thanks. I was hoping for a more straightforward way, but no such luck!